# Tunneling git through ssh (to get past a firewall): port specification interperted as relative path?

Tags: linux, ssh, git, tunnel

I have access to server A via ssh, and from server A can access server B, which runs gitlabs and contains the repository I need access to. When I am ssh'd into server A, I can run `git clone http://serverB/path/to/repo.git` successfully. Using `ssh://` or `git://` instead of `http://` does not work. (Errors are "does not appear to be a git repository" and "unable to connect to serverB," respectively.)

If I set up a tunnel like this:

```
ssh username@serverA -L 3333:serverB:80 -N
```

The following two attempts at git clones fail:

```
git clone http://localhost:3333/path/to/repo.git
```

Fails with: "fatal: repository not found"

```
git clone localhost:3333/path/to/repo.git
```

Prompts me for my password for serverB, and then fails with "fatal: 3333/path/to/repo.git does not appear to be a git repository." Of course, it isn't! My attempt at specifying localhost, port 3333, is clearly being interpreted as a relative path on serverB.

Is there a way to fix this? Is something fundamentally wrong with this approach?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Why does it not work

```
http://localhost:3333/path/to/repo.git
```

This fails because the URL's hostname is different (`localhost` vs `server2`), and as a result the server uses a different configuration.

All HTTP clients send the requested hostname to the server, and the server may choose from several configurations (virtual hosts) based on that name. This is how many websites (often hundreds) can share the same IP address at a hosting provider.

```
localhost:3333/path/to/repo.git
```

This fails because it's *not* an HTTP URL, or in fact any URL at all. (Git is not a web browser and doesn't assume `http://` by default.)

Instead it's an rcp-style SSH address in the form `[user@]host:path`. You might have seen it earlier as `git@github.com:foo/bar.git`, where the `ssh@` prefix is really just a SSH username.

Git treats it as equivalent to `ssh://[user@]host[:port]/path` URLs, except the rcp-style addresses do not have a port field at all.

### What to do

curl, the HTTP client used by Git, supports SOCKS proxies as provided by `ssh -D` dynamic tunnel.

1. Set up a dynamic (SOCKS) tunnel with:

   ```
   ssh username@serverA -D 1080 -N
   ```
2. Configure Git to use it as a proxy:

   Globally (or per-repository):

   ```
   git config [--global] http.proxy socks5://localhost:1080
   ```

   For a single command:

   ```
   git -c http.proxy=socks5://localhost:1080 clone http://serverB/repo.git
   ```

The `socks5` and `socks4` protocols perform DNS resolution on the client side, while `socks5h` and `socks4a` pass all hostnames through SOCKS to the SSH server.

Comment: When I try this, I get "Could not resolve host: serverB". But, I can access this same serverB URL via a web browser, using foxyproxy and the SOCKS tunnel created in (1.) Any ideas?

Comment: Try the `socks5h://` type in that case, or maybe `socks4a://`. That'll let the server do the hostname resolution, instead of the client.

Comment: `socks5h://` did it! Thanks for the help and detailed explanation.

Comment: where should command from item 1 be ran? At serverA, B or on my pc?

Comment: @eri0o: You run this on the same computer that you'll be running the Git commands on. So usually you run it on the local computer and it connects _to_ serverA (like regular ssh).